# Proof of Theorem 13.10 in Matsumura

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I'm confused about the last statement in the proof of Theorem 13.10 showing that the minimal prime divisor of determinantal ideal came from $r \times s$ matrix by picking $t \times t$ minors has height less than $(r-t+1)(s-t+1)$.

EDIT: I attached graphics originally, but you can access the searchable source from [google books](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Commutative_Ring_Theory/yJwNrABugDEC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=matsumura%20commutative%20ring&pg=PA104&printsec=frontcover).

[image: Proof of Theorem 13.10]

I understood how he got the conclusion that $PB$ is minimal prime divisor. But how can the author conclude that ``Since $a_{11}+X$ of $M'$ is not in $PB$, we have $\operatorname{ht}PB \leq (r-t+1)(s-t+1)"$? I don't know what kind of previous argument can be applied in this case. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I know this is a lot of text to type, but… Please do not rely on images: they are not searchable (either within the site or by web search engines), so that it would be difficult to locate the relevant information about this post. In addition, they don’t always display properly on all interfaces. Finally, screen readers cannot process them, so that your post is not accessible to people who use screen readers.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you for pointing me out. I added the link in google books, so that it can approachable screen reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If at least one of the elements of $M=(a_{ij})$ is invertible, then we can show that $I_t(M)=I_{t-1}(\widetilde M)$, where $\widetilde M$ is an $(r-1)\times(s-1)$ matrix which is obtained from $M$ by elementary row and column transformations. More precisely, if $a_{11}$ is invertible, then replace it by $1$ and make zero on the first row and column. The new matrix consisting from rows $2,\dots,r$ and columns $2,\dots,s$ is $\widetilde M$. Now we may use induction on the dimension of the matrix.

Then assume that all elements of $M$ are *not* invertible, that is, $a_{ij}\in P$ for all $i,j$. The trick is to replace the ring $R$ by $R[X]$, the prime ideal $P$ by $P[X]$, and $M$ by a matrix $M'$ having the same elements as $M$ excepting $a_{11}$ which is replaced by $a_{11}+X$. The point is that $a_{11}+X\notin P[X]$, and when localize $R[X]$ at $P[X]$ this element becomes invertible, and now can return to the previous setting.

Comment: Of course, there are some details that have to be checked, but everything we need is in the foregoing Lemma.

Comment: Great..! Yeah localization makes this element invertible! Thank you very much!